# How to match the first character in a String with a regexp?

Tags: java, regex, char

I need a regular expression to evaluate if the first character of a word is a lowercase letter or not.

I have this java code: `Character.toString(charcter).matches("[a-z?]")`

For example if I have those words the result would be:

- a13 => true
- B54 => false
- &32 => false

I want to match only one letter and I don't know if I need to use "?", "." or "{1}" after or inside "[a-z]"

Comment: You don't need a regexp to do that. That's a waste of resources and time. You can simply use `yourString.charAt(0)` and validate if this `char` is between `'a'` and `'z'`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a built in way to do this without regexes.

```
Character.isLowerCase(string.charAt(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this for your needs: `/^[a-z]/`

Answer (score 0):

You want to match if there's exactly one lowercase letter. As @Luiggi Medonza stated, you really do/should not need Regular Expressions for this, but if you want to use them, you most likely want this pattern:

```
[a-z]{1}
```

What `?` does is an optional match. You want a strict match of length 1, so you need `{1}`.

@Ted Hopp mentioned that you don't need the `{1}`. Your entire match should look like this:

```
entire_string.matches("^[a-z].+$")
```

Again, using built-in string methods will be much faster/better to use.

Comment: You don't need the `{1}` to match exactly one character. That is what will happen with no quantifier at all. Just use `[a-z]`.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any case where `{1}` would be needed in regex. Also `matches` checks if entire string can be matched by regex, not just part of string.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to match in [a-z] and [A-Z]. How would it be?

Comment: @DiegoGonzalez Sorry but you are asking question which suggest that  you didn't eve try to read any regex tutorial. You will be able to answer question from your current comment if you read about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here I got similar requirement like in a string first character should alphabet from a-z or A-Z. than the user can type anything like number or some limited symbols.

Solution

```
public static boolean designationValidate(String n) {
    int l = n.length();
    if (l >= 4) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-() ]*$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(n);
        return (matcher.find() && matcher.group().equals(n));
    } else
        return false;
}
```

in above example I am validation minimum character should more than 3 length and start with alphabet. If you want any other symbols you can enter there.
The method will return true if expressions match otherwise return false.

May this will helpful for you.